# How to split a code cell in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Using Jupyter Notebook I found that the function to split cells is very useful.
I would like to do that in Google Colab as well, but I can't find how to do it.

Can it be done? And if the answer is yes, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know how to do it via menu selections, but in Jupyter Lab the shortcut is "Ctrl+Shift+-" to split a cell.  Google Colab's shortcuts often replace "Ctrl+Shift+…" with "⌘/Ctrl+M …".

So, in this case, it would probably be "**⌘/Ctrl+M -**".

The "Keyboard shortcuts" window confirms this.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! However I have to highlight that the pressing of the 3 buttons has to be done very quickly, if not the (CTRL+M) combo will be interpreted as (CRTL+M M) and convert the code cell in text cell

Comment: ^  @SilentCloud comment is very important*** Also, on Mac use ⌘ command button in place of CRTL

Comment: As shown in Google Colab's "Keyboard shortcuts" window, the shortcut is  "⌘/Ctrl+M -".  I'll correct the answer…

Comment: This particular shortcut isn't working for me. Other `CTRL + M` shortcuts do work, but the one with `-` also just prints the character `-`. Frustrating.

Comment: @bluenote10 it works for me, tested 10 seconds ago, are you sure you didn't bind that shortcut to something else?

Comment: mac actually use CTRL not ⌘. At lease the current version

Comment: Just as bluenote10 notes, `ctrl+m, -` does not work for me (Windows/Firefox/CAFR keyboard). Redefining it to something else does work...

Answer (score 12):

If you go to:

```
google colab page menu -> Tools -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Split at Cursor
```

you can find it.

The default is **Ctrl + M -**, But you can modify it to whatever shortcut you prefer.