# viewing output in Colab line by line

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using google Colab to write python code. I see that I have to execute the whole
code in one go and the output appears at the bottom and I need to scroll down and to 
to view it. Especially if I want to just see the output of one of the command it doesn't
appear directly underneath it like in jupyter notebooks. Is there a way to achieve 
this in google colab?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can simply split the cell when you need to print a particular output and print it there. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692402/how-to-split-a-code-cell-in-google-colab)

Comment: That seems working. I will explore it.

Comment: @SilentCloud If I have to create a new file in google Colab do I have to create a new notebook or is there a way to create multiple files in the same notebook? That shortcut work. I was wondering if there is a UI way to do it as that would be easier to merge and split cells

Comment: What do you mean with "file" in Colab?

Comment: Like I open Colab and click on `+Code` button and start writing my code. Now I want to save this code and start writing another code.

Comment: Click in the right upper corner. File --> Save a Copy in Drive. Then to create a new, File --> New notebook